# Creating CTE of range(x) in SQL (Redshift)?

Tags: sql, range, amazon-redshift

I'd like to create a temp variable or CTE with column name weeks and values [1,...52]

What's the SQL (Redshift) equivalent of `range(52)`?

In python I could do

```py
import pandas as pd 
data = {'weeks':list(range(1,53))}
weeks = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But I can't make use of Python in my context, so I need to accomplish this purely in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a recursive CTE - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html

It will look something like

```
with recursive week_no(n) as (
select 1 as n 
union all
select n + 1 as n
from week_no
where n < 52
)
select n 
from week_no;
```

=========================================

Added some pedantic details to the query in case some aspect of your env is confusing the query:

```
with recursive week_no(n) as (
select 1::int as n 
union all
select n + 1 as n
from week_no wn
where wn.n < 52
)
select n 
from week_no;
```

Comment: Syntax error on `week_no(n)`, column not recognized) are there any additional steps needed to make this acceptable to Redshift?

Comment: The provided query run fine on my Redshift as is.  Is there another query not closed by a semicolon preceding this?  Please note that the recursive CTE needs to be first in the query.   I rewrote it to be more explicit in case your workbench is adding some info that is confusing Redshift - see update to answer.